# Shortest Simple Path with Two Designated Passing Points

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, shortest-path

I want to solve following simple problem.

> There is an undirected graph G with N vertices and M edges.
>   You have to find the length of shortest one, among simple path (we cannot use the vertex twice) from vertex 1 to N with passing two designated vertices X and Y.

So, if the graph is N=6, and X=2, Y=3, and there are M=6 edges which connects 1-2, 2-3, 2-6, 3-4, 4-5, 5-6, the shortest one will be 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6.

However, I cannot even produce a polynomial-time algorithm to judge if there is a valid path or not, so I'm asking for solution for it.

Comment: Have you used *Dijkstra's algorithm*?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yeah of course I know well about it. But the problem is that we cannot pass each vertex twice or more.

Comment: With Dijktra‘s algorithm you have two possible solutions: 1-X-Y-N and 1-Y-X-N.

Comment: @clemens However, there's a counter-example. The graph with N=4, X=2, Y=3, and M=4 edges for 1-2, 2-4, 1-3, 3-4. There is no valid path.

Comment: This is a counter example for the claim that your problem is _always_ solvable. But you can only find such a path, if the concrete graph has a solution. My suggested algorithm will find a solution, if one exists.

Comment: @clemens Not even so. The (possibly) first counter-example is N=6, X=2. Y=3 and edges are 1-2, 2-3, 2-6, 3-4, 4-5, 5-6. Your algorithm produces the answer with path 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 2 -> 6, but the correct answer should be 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6.

Comment: No. 1. your example has no valid solution. 2. The algorithm should search the subpaths not on the complete graph. You must remove all visited edges from the search graph during execution.

Comment: @clemens I think that you are thinking that we should find out "if there is a shortest path from 1 to N, which passes X and Y", but I'm asking different thing. What I am asking is "the shortest one among the simple path from 1 to N which passes X and Y."

Comment: If there was such a polynomial-time algorithm, you could use it to find the shortest cycle among N vertices, by trying every starting/ending and intermediate X, Y vertices, which takes N(N-1)(N-2)(N-3)/24 trials, and you could solve a Traveling Salesman in polynomial time.

Comment: @YvesDaoust While we should visit all vertices in Traveling Salesman Problem, we don't have to visit all vertices in this problem.

Comment: "if there is a shortest path from 1 to N, which passes X and Y" is a necessary condition for finding "the shortest one among the simple path from 1 to N which passes X and Y.", isn't it? So, we are talking about the same thing.

Comment: @clemens I don't think so. Of course, in my example of N=6, the shortest path from 1 to N is length 2 (1 -> 2 -> 6). But "the shortest one among the simple path from 1 to N which passes X and Y" is length 5, right?

Comment: This is the shortest path between 1 and N, but not the shortest path visiting X and Y. The shortest path doesn't fulfill necessary conditions of the question.

Comment: @clemens What do you mean by "this"? Also, I wrote in the question statement that we need to find "shortest one, among simple path from vertex 1 to N with passing two designated vertices X and Y."

Comment: I think you understand your problem much too complicated. In colloquial terms it can be described as: "What is the shortest way from the company to my home if I want to drive past the supermarket and my grandmother's house without having to drive twice on one street? It is obvious which solutions are possible here.

Comment: @clemens You are understanding almost correctly, except for which we should not pass same vertex twice, not meaning "passing same edge twice", however, I want to know the algorithm to find it.

Comment: Sorry, you're right: Replace _street_ with _crossroad_.

Comment: Does X have to be visited before Y ?

Comment: @DollarAkshay Not necessarily.

Comment: You don't understad @YvesDaoust comment. They are saying you cannot solve your problem in polynomial time.